# How to develop a QGIS plugin to fully run spatial queries with PostGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am developing a QGIS plugin that fully runs spatial queries with PostGIS.

I developed all spatial queries which need some adjustment.

I am looking for some resources or documents to know how to proceed.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @GISName! There is the plugin [PostGIS SQL Query Editor](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/postgisquery/) which you could look into by downloading and checking the scripts.

Comment: You could also have a look at the "Fast SQL Layer" plugin by [P. Carreira](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/1315/pablo): https://github.com/pablotcarreira/Fast-SQL-Layer